# Yandex Maps JS API: Problem with cluster events when dragging map with two fingers

Tags: javascript, dom-events, multi-touch, markerclusterer, yandex-maps

I disabled dragging a map with one finger on mobile devices

`map.behaviors.disable('drag');`

But there was a problem. The problem is as follows:

The map has a large number of clusters (initially (with a small zoom) - 90% of all placemarks on the map - clusters). When dragging a map with two fingers, if one of the fingers touches the cluster with a multitouch, the drag does not occur (the multitouch event on the map does not work - the multitouch event on the cluster is triggered) => the drag happens directly on the page of the site, and not on the map.

How to fix it? Maybe somehow pass the event cluster on the map?

Tried a lot of things, including hide all geoobjects, when a 'touchmove' event fires on the map element (but the multitouch event on the cluster still manages to work).

[An example of a problem in a JS sandbox](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JaxWPy) - go in from your mobile phone and try to drag the map where there are no clusters and where there is.

I tried to set the `clusterInteractivityModel: 'default#silent'` cluster option. Then the map is quietly dragged, but the 'click' event does not work.